# Error Project Euler # 8

Tags: c

I'm working on [Problem 8 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) where I have to find the largest product of 13 consecutive digits from a given 1000 digit number. I stored that number in a text file and then inputted it in my source code. My code compiles and runs, but my answer seems to be incorrect. Can anybody help me figure out where the error is?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int x,ar[1000],i = 0,prod = 0,tmp=1;
  FILE* fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
  if (fp == NULL)
  {
   printf("error");
   return 1;
  }
  while((x = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
      ar[i] = x;
      i++;
  }
  /*for(int m =0;m<999;m++)
  {
    printf("%d",ar[m]);
  }*/
  for(int j =0;j <= 986;j++)
  {
      for(int k=j;k<j+13;k++)
      {
        tmp = tmp * ar[k];
      }
      if(tmp > prod)
      {
        prod = tmp;
      }
  }
  printf("%i",prod);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for one, 986+12 is only 998 digits, so you're missing the last combo.

Comment: 9^13 = 2.5e12 so you need to make sure that `prod` is more than 32 bits.

Comment: See ASCII, and the difference between 0 and '0' etc.

Comment: Are you ever re-assigning the value of `tmp` to 1 after the second `for-loop`?

Answer (score 3):

The product of 13 consecutive digits may exceeds range of `int` which you're using for `tmp`. You need data types that supports a wider range. Maybe 64bit ones like `unsigned long long` would do.

Also as @deviantfan has pointed out, you're reading characters, and `'0'` as an character is not the same thing as a number `0`. Read about ASCII.

Another problem is that the logic of `tmp` is not correct: you didn't re-initialize it to `1` after each 13 step loop.

#### EDITED:

Reply to your comment: I suppose in this case the best solution is to read the data as characters, however after that you could convert the ASCII to integer, e.g.:

```
while((x = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    // x - '0' does the conversion, 
    // e.g. the expression obtains 0 from '0' - '0', and 5 from '5' - '0'
    ar[i] = x - '0';
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Note: The product of 5 consecutive digits may exceed the range of `int` as `INT_MAX` need only be >= 32767. The product of 10 consecutive digits may exceed 2147483647, a common value of `INT_MAX`.  `unsigned long long` can handle the product of 20 digits.

Comment: So how to read them as numbers and not chars? I have changed the data type of prod to unsigned long long.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the product of digit chars, not of the digits they represent.  '1' != 1.

Comment: So should i force ably change them to an int?

Comment: I don't know what "forcibly" is supposed to mean in this context, nor, for that matter, what you mean by "change them to an int".  This is not a datatype issue, it is a *value* issue.  One alternative is to subtract '0' from each array element after you read in the array.  Another is to do that conversion at the point of use.